# Is there a built in program in any of the top EDA software to ease production of Technical Publications?

Tags: pcb-design, eda, documentation

I have been assigned to design a PCB and now I have to create Technical Documentation for in-house use. I tried googling this information but it shows the documentation for the software which is not what I was asking for. Software like Siemens Solid Edge have built in support to create technical documentation. Do any EDA software also have this option?

Comment: your question, asking for software recommendation, belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: All the top packages can do those things. Altium, for example, has the 'draftsman' module which greatly simplifies generating assembly drawings and PCB masters.